# Shortcut in Visual Studio 2010 to generate all possible Case's in Switch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, switch-statement

I can't find key binding to expand all possible cases in switch,
eg. have switch with enum argument, in Borland C++ i doing this with <kbd>TAB</kbd> key
while switch code is selected.

I want to do this in Visual Studio 2010.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It C++ it's not possible to do this.  The IDE just doesn't have support for that operation.

In C# you can do this with the *switch* code snippet:

- Type "switch" in the IDE which will select the snippet in intellisense
- Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert the snippet which will move the cursor inside the parens
- Type the expression to switch on and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will expand out the known cases into the IDE.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, unless resharper breaks it

Comment: Just for future reference to reflect on @Jaider's question: As far as I know, you can only generate the scaffold with the same approach. Put in Select press <Tab>, populate the variable to build the cases on, however, this will only generate a case 1, a case 2 and a case else, but doesn't populate them automatically. :( Unsure why. This is in VS2010 Pro. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was duo to resharper installation which does it differently.

after entering the switch and the parameter place the curser in the switch body and then you need to click on the lamp icon on the left or clicking Alt+Enter.